# Why do I get a "Null pointer exception" from spring security?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Securityand can't see why I keep having the message with "Null Pointer Exception", I read the other posts and made some changes but keep having this error. It seems that it does not communiate with my database. Please help me. Thanks

Here is my code:
Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd

">

<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
p:suffix=".jsp"/>

<bean id="filterMultipartResolver" 
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"> 
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="-1" />
</bean> 

<!-- a chaque espace de nom correspond un schema, les 2 points sont suivis d'un prefixe -->
<!-- Dans schema location: A chaque schema est associe un fichier xsd  -->
<context:component-scan base-package="demos.controller"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<!-- Spring s'adresse au conteneur JPA de Glassfish. Le fichier persistence.xml situé dans META-INF du classpath est utilisé -->
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/springsecuritybasicJNDI" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>

<!--  Dao -->
<bean id="roleDAO" class="demos.dao.RoleDAOImpl"/>
<bean id="userDAO" class="demos.dao.UserDAOImpl"/>


<bean id="domainUser" class="demos.model.User" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>


</beans>
```

Spring Security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403Page.html"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/sec/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_MODERATOR','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <form-login login-page="/user-login.html"
            default-target-url="/success-login.html"
             authentication-failure-url="/error-login.html"
             login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>

        <logout logout-success-url="/success-logout.html"
         logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
          invalidate-session="true" />

    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="MyUserDetail">
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="MyUserDetail" class="demos.service.CustomUserDetailsService" autowire="byType" />

</beans:beans>
```

My customerDetailsService:

```
package demos.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import demos.dao.UserDAO;


@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;    

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        // Declare a null Spring User
        UserDetails user = null;

        System.out.println("serviceLogin: "+login);
        demos.model.User domainUser = userDAO.getUser(login);

        if(domainUser == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserName "+login+" not found");
        }

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;
System.out.println("loginuser: " + domainUser.getLogin() );

        user = new User(
                domainUser.getLogin(), 
                domainUser.getPassword(), 
                enabled, 
                accountNonExpired, 
                credentialsNonExpired, 
                accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getId()) );

        return user;

    }


    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
        return authList;
    }

    public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {

        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (role.intValue() == 1) {
            roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
            roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");
        } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
            roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
        }
        return roles;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

Here is the UserDao:

```
package demos.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import demos.model.User;


@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;


    @Override
    public User getUser(String login) {

        System.out.println("daoLogin1: "+ login);

        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

        System.out.println("daoLogin2: "+login);

        String query = "select u from User u where u.login like ?1 ";
        TypedQuery<User> q = em.createQuery(query,User.class); 
        q.setParameter(1, login);
//      q.setParameter(1, '%'+login+'%');
        userList = q.getResultList();
        if (userList.size() > 0)
            return userList.get(0);
        else
            return null;    
    }

}
```

Here is the UserService layer:

```
package demos.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import demos.dao.UserDAO;
import demos.model.User;

    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

        @Autowired
        private UserDAO userDAO;

        public User getUser(String login) {
            return userDAO.getUser(login);
        }


}
```

And the User class:

```
package demos.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String login;

    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    )
    private Role role;


    //getter et setter

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", login=" + login + ", password=" + password
                + ", role=" + role + "]";
    }


}
```

With the Role Class:

```
package demos.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String role;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    )
    private Set<User> userRoles;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Set<User> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<User> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Role [id=" + id + ", role=" + role + ", userRoles=" + userRoles
                + "]";
    }


}
```

Here is the message that I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at demos.service.CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserDetailsService.java:34)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
    ... 56 more

|Infos: serviceLogin: adm
```

Let me know if you need more details, but I cannot see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`UserDao` is not injected into `CustomUserDetailsService` because they are defined in different Spring contexts (xml files in this case).

Consider importing one of them into another if it is essential to keep these definitions in separate contexts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've imported the UserDao details on the Spring.xml file and it's working. As I keep learning how to use spring security, would you advise me to have only one xml file instead of having dispatcher.servlet.xml and the spring security.xml? I'm very new. Thanks again

Comment: It is reasonable to separate a context if it is long ang hard to maintain. Or if you develop multi-module application with separate context in each module. And servlet context is usually divided from main application one.